# React-Native module is being looked for in an invalid directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, babeljs

I am helping with a project. The code is written mainly in TypeScript. We use babel to translate ES6->ES5. The front-end is developed with react-native. Recently, after updating babel, packages became "missing." I manually locally installed each package and one-by-one got the project to compile up to the below error, shown sometime after packer starts.

```
+ react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev true --bundle-output /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gjqyntaykupdmhaecjypkdppuznf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/shmukler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gjqyntaykupdmhaecjypkdppuznf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
uncaught error Error: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module LinkedStateMixin from /Users/shmukler/Projects/myproject/myapp-ios/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native.js: Invalid directory /Users/node_modules/LinkedStateMixin
```

I installed LinkedStateMinin with npm install react-addons-pure-render-mixin - much like all other packages. Why is it looking for it at
/Users/node_modules/LinkedStateMixin ? How can I change that? Where are those paths specified? Could I manually hack the path just to get the app to build, as a temporary way to move forward?

Thank you

Comment: Seems like potential directory path is wrong, but I don't know React-Native internals, at all. Could be something else. Please advise, if you know how to set path, or anything about this, really.

Comment: Which version of nmp are you using? I had problems with npm 3, reverting to npm 2 solved the problem.

Comment: I am using npm 2.14.12. Since the problem started appearing after updating babel etc, I doubt that it is npm related.

Comment: @MosheShmukler, I am facing the same issue. I am also using npm 2.14.12. Please help if you fixed it.